# Specifying function call to const vs. non-const?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

In my code I am specifying two functions that do the same thing, except one returns a const object and is specified as const:

```
const Object& getObject(...) const {...}
```

while the other is not:

```
Object& getObject(...) {...}
```

When I try to call `getObject` like this:

```
Object o = getObject(...);
```

it is using the const version, when I need to use the non-const. How can I specify which one to use?

Comment: Show how are you calling it

Comment: If you assign `getObject` to something that is a non-const lvalue, then it should use the non-const version.

Comment: @P0W I added how I am attempting to call it.

Comment: Did you try `Object &o = getObject(...);` ?

Comment: Both your functions return a reference so you are copy initialising `o` no matter what.

Comment: Why do you "need to use" the `non-const` version?  Aren't the two functions, on a high level, performing the same job?

Comment: BTW, if you ever have a legitimate reason why you need to force the `const` overload to be called, this is how you do it: `static_cast<const MyClass*>(this)->getObject()`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I needed to use the non-const version because I needed to change the object.

Comment: You won't be able to change the original object the way you're doing it, since `o` is not a reference.

Comment: @JonathanWrona The issue is not that you called the wrong function, it is that you assigned the return value to a *brand new* object, not a reference.   If you just assigned to a reference, then that would have sufficed.

Comment: @wilkesybear that's not how it works, function overload is not affected by what you do with the return value afterwards

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you actually want to use the reference that is returned by `getObject`, you should do

```
Object& o = getObject(...);
```

Otherwise, using `Object o = ...` will just invoke the `Object` copy constructor. However, this change won't affect which `getObject` function is invoked--that depends on whether the object containing the `getObject` calls is const.

Comment: This answers the real question (how to get a reference rather than a copy), but the reasoning is bogus. The function call will choose the same override whatever you do with the result. It will choose the `const` overload if called on a `const` object, and the other one otherwise. If this works, then the code in the question was also calling the non-const overload, then copying the result when using it to initialise an object rather than a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is really `Object o = getObject(...);`  then you must be calling this from inside a member function of the same class offering the `getObject` member function.

You say the `const` overload is being called; that means that you are inside a `const` instance of an object (or at least, being a const reference).  Therefore you cannot reliably call a non-const function.

You could cast around the const by going:

```
Object o = const_cast< TheClassName >(*this).getObject(...);
```

This probably will cause undefined behaviour though. Also there seems to be a larger design problem: In general it seems like a poor idea for a const function to actually return a different object than the non-const function.

(I am assuming they return different objects, as if they return the same object then your original code will be working just fine).